# What's the meaning of "sink through time"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could you please tell me what the meaning of the phrase is?

> I sank through time.

I think it means "she(the speaker) wasted time she had" but I amnot sure.

The full text is:

A week after the wedding I broke up with Nick—callously, I’m ashamed
to say. I never told him of my life before, never sketched for him the world
that had invaded and obliterated the one he and I had shared. I could have
explained. I could have said, “That place has a hold on me, which I may
never break.” That would have got to the heart of it. Instead **I sank through
time.** It was too late to confide in Nick, to take him with me wherever I was
going. So I said goodbye.

Comment: I don't think it can be interpreted literally, rather as a matter of reading comprehension/interpretation. Different people might give differing explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description

> **I sank through time.**

Is a metaphor, where the speaker is being *passive* as in *sinking in water*.
This is in contrast to taking action, which she didn't

> I never told him...
>   I could have explained...
>   I could have said...

until

> It was too late...

Comment: You have not explained it.